Catching Kotlin exceptions in exception handler freezes the main thread
I'm setting the default uncaught exception handler using setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler interface, as shown below:
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        LOG("MainActivity.onCreate(Bundle?)")

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // Register the 'catch-all' exception handler
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(CustomUncaughtExceptionHandler())

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // Example of a call to a native method
        binding.sampleText.text = stringFromJNI()

        testExceptionHandler()

        LOG("Returning from Activity.onCreate()")
    }
}

I explicitly throw an exception from onCreate to test the exception handler:
private fun testExceptionHandler() {

    LOG("testExceptionHandler()")

    LOG("Raising exception...")
    throw NullPointerException()
}

The exception is thrown and caught by the uncaught exception handler. My CustomUncaughtExceptionHandler, which I registered earlier, is defined as follows:
class CustomUncaughtExceptionHandler: Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    override fun uncaughtException(p0: Thread, p1: Throwable) {

        LOG("uncaughtException(Thread, Throwable)")

        var exceptionType: String = "(null)"
        when (p1) {
            is IndexOutOfBoundsException -> {
                exceptionType = "IndexOutOFBoundsException"
            }

            is NullPointerException -> {
                exceptionType = "NullPointerException"
            }

            is ArithmeticException -> {
                exceptionType = "ArithmeticException"
            }

            is RuntimeException -> {
                exceptionType = "RuntimeException"
            }

            else -> {
                exceptionType = "Unknown"
            }
        }
        LOG("Exception type = $exceptionType")

        LOG("Already in main thread... Preparing to display alert...")
        displayAlert(exceptionType)

        LOG("Returning from default uncaught exception handler...")
    }
    
    private fun displayAlert(exceptionType: String) {

        LOG("Displaying error on foreground activity...")

        val builder : AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(ContextMgr.activityCtx!!)
        builder.setTitle("Something went wrong!!")
        builder.setMessage(exceptionType)
        builder.setCancelable(false)
        builder.setPositiveButton("Restart") { _, _ ->
            LOG("Restart the app...")
        }

        val alertdialog : AlertDialog = builder.create()
        alertdialog.show()
    }
}

In the exception handler, I try to capture the kind of exception thrown, and then show an AlertDialog to the user.
The problem is, the UI is stuck like this:

The normal flow without throwing any exception would have resulted a minimal UI with a text - "Hello from C++". This is the UI of the Android native project template.
Looking at the logs,
MainActivity.onCreate(Bundle?)
testExceptionHandler()
Raising exception...
....
// stack trace
....
uncaughtException(Thread, Throwable)
Exception type = RuntimeException
Already in main thread... Preparing to display alert...
Returning from default uncaught exception handler...

As shown in the logs, in onCreate, a NullPointerException is thrown, invokes the uncaught exception handler which tries to display an alert... but the UI looks as attached above.
The logs also indicate that the flow never returned from onCreate, and onResume, onStart never got invoked.
So, my AlertDialog failed because an exception happened, the Activity never completed its lifecycle and therefore cannot show anything to user? If true, how can I remedy this? If possible, I'd like to show my AlertDialog, or atleast the process should terminate instead of showing... whatever this UI is.
Update1 - My environment:
Link to my project - AndroidExceptionHandling
AS details: Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Patch 2
Emulator details:

AvdId: Tiramisu_Pixel_8_Pro_API_33_
image.androidVersion.api: 33
image.sysdir.1: system-images\android-33\google_apis_playstore\x86_64\


"the flow never returned from onCreate" -- that would cause the other problems that you cite. "Looking at the logs" -- those logs do not match the code in your question. And your code has a disturbing-looking blockExceptionThread = false;, suggesting that somewhere you are intentionally blocking the exception thread, which is the main thread. Since blockExceptionThread does not otherwise exist in your code, it is difficult to help you further.

@CommonsWare blockExceptionThread = false - I was using this to block a worker thread, which had invoked the uncaught exception handler. The worker thread was blocked until user has responded to my alert. I just want to see what happens if I don't return from uncaught exception handler - that's all. This is no longer used, but the property is still declared and used in this part of the code...removing it now.

@CommonsWare, those logs do not match the code in your question - I've removed the huge stack trace and other system logs... I've shared here only the logs printed by my app's LOG method.  My intent was to remove unnecessary comments and focus on exception handling issue. I've attached the original project to this post, in case it helps.

You are throwing an exception in onCreate() which is running on the main (UI) thread, then you are "handling" that exception in your UncaughtExceptionHandler. You can't really do what you want to do, because Android has detected an uncaught exception, and expects to terminate the current thread, but you are "handling" the exception and NOT terminating the current thread.
Generally speaking, in an UncaughtExceptionHandler all you can/should do is to collect information about the exception, try to write this data to a file and then terminate the app. You can do this by calling System.exit(), or you can try the following:

Create a class like MyApplication that extends Application
In MyApplication.onCreate() save a reference to the DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler in a property that is publically accessable
Add your custom Application class to the manifest <application> declaration
In MainActivity.onCreate() set the DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler to your exception handler.
In your exception handler, do whatever you want to do (save the exception information in a file or whatever) and then call ucaughtException() on the original DefaultExceptionHandler which you saved a reference to in MyApplication, passing the arguments through that you got in your exception handler.

This should properly close the app.
You cannot show a Dialog or do anything with the UI in an UncaughtExceptionHandler if the uncaught exception was thrown on the Main (UI) thread, as the main thread is the one that handles the UI and it is going to terminate (one way or another).
When your app starts again, it should check if there is a file with an uncaught exception info in it, and if so, it can show the user the file, or send it to a server or whatever before starting up.

Here are a few relevant links to similar solutions:

Replacing Default Uncaught Exception Handler To Avoid Crash Dialog
https://github.com/jorexdeveloper/android-eh
https://sterl.org/2016/02/android-global-exception-handler/
https://medium.com/android-news/handling-uncaught-exceptions-in-android-d818ffb20181
https://enigmaofcoding.wordpress.com/2016/06/12/implementing-uncaught-exception-handler-in-android/


So, when the uncaught exception handler is invoked, the thread which invoked is killed when returned? Is there some documentation reg this behavior?... would like to know more about this and other boundaries reg exception handling in Android.

Is it okay to quit the app by itself (like System.exit)? It seems an Android app should never quit by itself and just leave it to the user to kill the app (by swiping it up from the Overview screen) when required. So, is this fine? Does this get you kicked out of Android's app store?

Yes, it is OK to quit the app like that, in this case. Your app basically already crashed if you have an uncaught exception the main (UI) thread. This won't get you kicked out of the app store (that I know of). It would be better, of course, to prevent the app from generating uncaught exceptions on the main (UI) thread, if possible, by catching those exceptions much earlier.

Did you make any changes as I suggested? Are you able to solve your issue?

Yes. As suggested, captured the default handler and invoked it at the end of by my custom handler. App doesn't hang in a weird state now. Thank you.

when you want exactly to show the Alert , i think you need to change the way you wanna do it , just save what exception you have and when the user open again the app show the Alert or a Fragment to show The LAST CRASH details , it better .
